# can not set div.scrollLeft in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with some input fields aligned in one row horizontally. And when there is an error I want to scroll to the input element where the error was but I can not set the container `#preferences` scrollLeft.

```
<form id="preferences">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="" id="new_username" name="username"/>

    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="aww:/ add an email" id="email" name="email"/>

    <input type="password" value="" placeholder="password" id="old_password" name="password"/>
    <input type="password" value="" placeholder="new password" id="new_password" name="new_password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="update">
</form>
```

```
#preferences {
    text-align: center
    margin: 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```
var email = document.getElementById('email'),
    preferences = document.getElementById('preferences');

preferences.scrollLeft = email.offsetLeft;
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot set? Do you get any error or it just doesn't do any effect? What is `#preferences` and what styles does it have? Be more specific and show markup and css.

Comment: Nothing happens and no error. See my updated question please. @Gabriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container (the form) hasn't a defined width, so it just expands laterally. You cannot scroll it because it doesn't have overflow. You could, however, scroll the parent if it does have fixed width or it's the body.

See:

```js
preferences.scrollLeft = 250; //it works...
```

```css
#preferences {
    text-align: center
    margin: 10px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px; /*if you set the width*/
}
```

```html
<form id="preferences">
    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="" id="new_username" name="username"/>

    <input type="text" value="" placeholder="aww:/ add an email" id="email" name="email"/>

    <input type="password" value="" placeholder="password" id="old_password" name="password"/>
    <input type="password" value="" placeholder="new password" id="new_password" name="new_password"/>

    <input type="submit" value="update">
</form>
```

Comment: it does not work using element.offsetLeft because I need to get the position and preferences needs to be with a width of 100%.

Comment: That's correct, it's exactly what I said. I used 300px in my example, but it could be 100%, the point is to have fixed width.

Comment: It does not work for me. There must be another problem.